# PHP preg_match triple braces inside double braces

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to write a regex to find a string between double braces, but it stops if it founds triple braces.

Someone could help me, please?

`{{prefix this is 
an {{{example}}} 
and can't stop 
on example word.}}
{{anoter_prefix another
double braces and I
have to find both}}`

REGEX:

```
'/\{\{prefix(.*)?\}\}/sU'
```

---

Edit:

Sorry, I forgot to say I need to break lines

Thanks!

Comment: You are using `/U` which makes the quantifiers lazy.

Comment: Do you have multiple occurrences of such strings in a larger text? Or is it a standalone string?

Comment: Sorry, I edited it. I forgot to mention that I need to break lines. Is that what /U does, right?

Comment: No, that is what `/s` does, it makes the dot match a newline.

Comment: Yes, I do @WiktorStribiżew. I can't get first {{ and last }} because there are other ocurrences

Comment: Well, I know how to make a workaround. I can replace all }}} by another string, execute regex and replace the triple braces back, but I would like to learn the correct way to do that with only regex.

Comment: `'~(?<!{){{prefix(?:[^{}]|(?<!})}(?:}{2,})?|(?<!{){(?:{{2,})?)*}}(?!})~s'` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/juztwT/2)) works, but is rather complex.

Comment: Don't know if any of the above solution worked for you. If not, does [`(?<!{){{(?!{)(?:prefix|another_prefix).*?(?<!})}}(?!})`](https://regex101.com/r/daa7UF/1) regex work for you?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it works!! Thank you!!!

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi it does the first step, but don't get the another_prefix. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Thank you all guys.

Comment: Should I post an answer?

Comment: @ThiagoGyboskiMengatto: It captures both the matches if you see my demo. In your original example, you had a typo `anoter_prefix` may be due to which it doesn't match.

Answer (score 0):

Its a simple matter of insuring double brace delimiters `{{` - `}}`.

Then inject that into a recursion.

`(?<!{){(?!{{)({(?:[^{}]++|(?1))*})}`

https://regex101.com/r/lSEvCX/1

Formatted Code:

```
 (?<! { )               # Not a brace behind

 {                      # Open Brace ( 1st of double )
 (?! {{ )               # Tripple open not allowed
 (                      # (1 start), recursion function
      {                      # Open Brace ( 2nd of double )
      (?:
           [^{}]++                # Not braces, possesive
        |                       # or, 
           (?1)                   # Recurse a single open/close brace pair
      )*
      }                      # Close Brace ( closure)
 )                      # (1 end), recursion
 }                      # Close Brace
```

Comment: It does the first step, but I couldn't get the "another_prefix". Thank you anyway!

Comment: @ThiagoGyboskiMengatto  -  `If someone else is looking for something like what I needed, Wiktor gave us the way`   _LOL_ ROFL..

Answer (score 0):

You may use a regex that will match `{{` with no `{` before, then matches `prefix`, then matches any amount of chars other than `{` and `}` or single `{` / `}` or 3 or more `{`s or `}`s, up to a `}}` substring not followed with `}`:

```
'~(?<!{){{prefix(?:[^{}]|(?<!})}(?:}{2,})?|(?<!{){(?:{{2,})?)*(?<!})}}(?!})~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/juztwT/4)

**Details**

- `(?<!{)` - a negative lookbehind that requires no `{` immediately to the left of the current location
- `{{prefix` - a literal substring
- `(?:[^{}]|(?<!})}(?:}{2,})?|(?<!{){(?:{{2,})?)*` - zero or more repetitions of:

  - `[^{}]` - any char but `{` and `}`
  - `|` - or
  - `(?<!})}(?:}{2,})?` - `}` not preceded with `}` and optionally followed with 2 or more `}` chars
  - `|` - or
  - `(?<!{){(?:{{2,})?`  - `{` not preceded with `{` and optionally followed with 2 or more `{` chars
- `(?<!})` - no `}` immediately to the left of the current location is allowed
- `}}` - a `}}` substring...
- `(?!})` - ... not immediately followed with `}`.

Comment: This solution actually matches wrongly where it also captures a match when there are three ending `}}}` instead of exactly just two `}}` [Check this](https://regex101.com/r/juztwT/3)

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi It is not wrong if [it does the job for OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55198404/php-preg-match-triple-braces-inside-double-braces/55210639#comment97157103_55198404). Three `}}` at the end are actually a valid scenario since inside `{{....}}` there can be any amount of `{`, `}`, `{{{`, `}}}`, etc.

Comment: At any rate, `(?<!})`  before  `}}` fixes that.

Answer (score -1):

If someone else is looking for something like what I needed, Wiktor gave us the way.

`'~(?<!{){{prefix(?:[^{}]|(?<!})}(?:}{2,})?|(?<!{){(?:{{2,})?)*}}(?!})~s'`

Thank you guys

Comment: I can post my solution myself. Please refrain from copying others' solutions. You do not even need the `s` flag here.

Comment: Please consider accepting my answer since my solution worked for you and removing this "answer".

Comment: Please finalize the question by removing this "answer" of yours and accepting my answer since you say it worked for you. This way, you will gain some more reputation rather than losing it.